# Select Form: Database request many times

Tags: php, database, forms, select

I have a database that I need to use to do select.
The select is repeat many times (days of the week).

I can't do a loop for because it can have some "gap" in the id so I use the while.
The problem is that for each select I need to call the database again and I think it's not really a good solution. I would like to find another solution which isn't so "heavy"

Here is my code:

```
<select name="monday">
    <option value="none">Monday </option>
<?php 
$Requete2 = "SELECT * FROM `record`"; 
$Result2 = mysql_query($Requete2) or die(mysql_error());
$rows2 = mysql_num_rows($Result2);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($Result2)){ ?>  
    <option value="<?php echo ($row2['id'] - 1); ?>"><?php echo $row2['name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>  
</select>

<select name="tuesday">
<option value="none">Tuesday </option>
<?php 
$Requete2 = "SELECT * FROM `record`"; 
$Result2 = mysql_query($Requete2) or die(mysql_error());
$rows2 = mysql_num_rows($Result2);
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($Result2)){ ?>  
<option value="<?php echo ($row2['id'] - 1); ?>"><?php echo $row2['name']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>  
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your problem. btw your code is full with duplicate lines

Comment: yes that's my problem. I have 7 select like this and all the time need to ask the database so I would like to know how can I make it better

Comment: Why is your SQL query the same on the 2 requests? You will print out the same data for monday as for tuesday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print out the same for every day you can use this(I havn't tested it for syntax errors):

```
<?php
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `record`"; 
$query = mysql_query($sql_query) or die(mysql_error());
$optionHtml = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 
    $optionHtml .= '<option value="' . ($row["id"] - 1) . '">' . $row["name"] . '</option>';
}
?>
<select name="monday">
    <option value="none">Monday</option>
    <?php echo $optionHtml; ?>
</select>

<select name="tuesday">
    <option value="none">Tuesday</option>
    <?php echo $optionHtml; ?> 
</select>
```